# Sample irregular list of numbers with a set delta

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simpler way, using e.g. `numpy`, to get `samples` for a given `X` and `delta` than the below code?

```py
>>> X = [1, 4, 5, 6, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 30]
>>> delta = 5
>>> samples = [X[0]]
>>> for x in X:
...     if x - samples[-1] >= delta:
...         samples.append(x)
        
>>> samples
[1, 6, 11, 20, 25, 30]
```

Comment: You mean other than wrapping it in a function?

Comment: 'pythonic' is probably not the right word here. I'll edit the question

Comment: Are your numbers always in ascending order ?

Comment: You mean a vectorised way probably? That's quite hard, seems like you need to iterate `X`  every time samples are appended.

Comment: @AlainT. Yeah they are always in ascending order.

Comment: @mathfux Yes vectorized, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to "vectorize" the process for performance reasons (e.g. using numpy), you could compute the number of elements that are less than each element plus the delta.  This will give you indices for the items to select with the items that need to be skipped getting the same index as the preceding ones to be kept.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 4, 5, 6, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 30])
delta = 5

i = np.sum(X<X[:,None]+delta,axis=1) # index of first to keep
i = np.insert(i[:-1],0,0) # always want the first, never the last
Y = X[np.unique(i)]       # extract values as unique indexes

print(Y)
[ 1  6 11 20 25 30]
```

*This assumes that the numbers are in ascending order*

**[EDIT]**

As indicated in my comment, the above solution is flawed and will only work some of the time.  Although vectorizing a python function does not fully leverage the parallelism (and is slower than the python loop), it is possible to implement the filter like this

```
X = np.array([1, 4, 5, 6, 10,11,12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 30])
delta = 5

fdelta = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b:a if a+delta>b else b,2,1)
Y = X[X==fdelta.accumulate(X,dtype=np.object)]

print(Y)
[ 1  6 11 20 25 30]
```

Comment: This is some serious magic :)

Comment: Unfortunately my magic is flawed.  It only works in some cases but there are many sequences where it will not be able to skip tightly grouped clusters.  I suggest you unaccept this answer so that you may get a better one.